# Setting repeating alarm when creating Application - why does it trigger immediately

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have an application object declared in the manifest and this code runs when the application runs. What I want to accomplish is to set an alarm:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;
    persister = new Persister();
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    registerAlarms();
}

public void registerAlarms() {

    String sleepString = sharedPref.getString("time_sleepLog", "08:00");
    String[] pieces = sleepString.split(":");
    int sleepHour = Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]);
    int sleepMinute = Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]);

    String eveningString = sharedPref.getString("time_eveningLog", "20:00");
    pieces = null;
    pieces = eveningString.split(":");
    int eveningHour = Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]);
    Log.v(TAG, "eveningHour in registerAlarms: " + eveningHour);
    int eveningMinute = Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]);
    // create calendar objects pointing to the next time this clock will
    // occur
    Calendar sleepCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    sleepCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sleepHour);
    sleepCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sleepMinute);
    sleepCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar eveningCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    eveningCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, eveningHour);
    eveningCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, eveningMinute);
    sleepCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent syncIntent = new Intent(this, SleepNotificationReceiver.class);
    syncIntent.putExtra("MoodSleepLogAlarm", 0);
    PendingIntent sleepPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            syncIntent, 0);
    // then set the alarms
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sleepCal.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sleepPending);
    Log.v(TAG, "Alarm for sleep registered at " + sleepCal.getTime());
    }
```

I log in the broadcastreceiver to check if it runs with:

```
Log.v(TAG, "Context: " + context.getClass().getName())
```

I can see this in logcat 4 seconds after starting my application as 0

```
6-27 17:59:29.492: V/SleepNotificationReceiver(2609): Context: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
```

When I call the `registerAlarms()` via a button it doesn't happend. So it is only when called onCreate.

**Why does it run the broadcast receiver after 4 seconds?** (It does also run the broadcastreceiver with the same context given at the given times in my settings screen - but I need it to not run when I set it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are setting the alarm repeating, the second parameter indicates when the alarm has to go off the first time, so I think that if you type `sleepCal.getTimeInMillis()` and you are in the "future" compared to this time, the alarm is going off instantly.

Check that second parameter if it's in the future because I think that you are not setting the day or month in your calendar.

Comment: seems true! Thanks! I have to create logics for checking if the time has passed this day, if passed I add a day to the calendar. :)